# Photoshop: Undoing after shift-clicking with brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is something very basic, but annoys me since ever. Using the brush tool (B), I can click at point "A", then <kbd>shift</kbd>+click at point "B". A line is drawn from "A" to "B". Simple and effective - I use this a lot to fine-tune layer masks.

If I undo, line is undone, but point "A" is not. Unfortunately, I cannot <kbd>shift</kbd>+click "B" again - I got a point at "B" instead of a line.

Am I missing some option to keep the <kbd>shift</kbd>+click behavior after undoing?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the History panel, you will see that there's actually 2 events created there. One for the first click and another one for the <kbd>shift</kbd>+second click. If you press undo you will only remove the second click, which created the line.

Simply select the event above the first click in the History panel and the two events will be undone.

You can also press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> if you use a PC) two times which allows you to undo more than one step.

Comment: I already know about these two events. All I want is to redo the line without needing to undo both events. It would be faster and easier to "Cmd+Z" and "Shift-Click", instead of two "Cmd-Alt-Z" and two more clicks.

Comment: Then you'll have to solve it by using a script (I'm not sure it's possible though) since it's not a native function in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

At least for now, there’s no way to do that. [As Henrik Ekblom said](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38042/19174), Photoshop relies on events and actions. So if you are going to undo, you will undo an action. But in your case the action for a straight line is *clickA → shift → clickB.* When you undo you will do a *clickA → shift → clickB → cmdZ.* Therefore when you go back to *shift* and perform *clickB,* you will get *clickA → shift → clickB → cmdZ → clickB.* And that’s why the action doesn’t work.

I hope this explains how Photoshop works with that action. Some script may be able to work around that problem but I don’t believe so, maybe a new shortcut and a script could resolve that.